# Help identifying part from car (possibly BMW)

Tags: bmw, part-identification

Is anyone able to identify what this is? This is an artifact from property damage caused by a car. I am curious if the number at the top would help identify the vehicle, or if it is just a common part number.

[image: Part]

Comment: Hint: search for "BMW DN 14390".

Answer (score 2):

A quick google of the part number shows that it is a -
BMW 1 series E87 m sport rear BUMPER TOW EYE COVER

Look on eBay and you will find them for sale.

It may also fit other BMWs though.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to work out the year of manufacture of that part but not the specific vehicle.

Even getting the year and possibly week of manufacture would not be easy.

So, you are unlikely to be able to find the vehicle.